# My game against AI, please analyze

Tags: analysis, engines, online-chess

```
[Event "4444 vs AI"]
[Site "multiplayerchess.com"]
[Date "2015.08.12"]
[Round "1"]
[White "4444"]
[Black "AI"]
[Result "1-0"]

[FEN ""]
1. e4 e5 2. d3 d5 3. Ne2 g5 4. Nbc3 d4 5. Nb5 c6 6. Na3 Bxa3 7. bxa3 b5 8. Rb1 Be6 9. Rb4 Bxa2 10. f4 gxf4 11. Nxf4 exf4 12. Bxf4 a5 13. Rb2 Qh4+ 14. g3 Qe7 15. Rxa2 Nd7 16. Bh3 Nc5 17. Qg4 Nf6 18. Qg7 Rg8 19. Qh6 Rd8 20. O-O Ne6 21. e5 Rg6 22. exf6 Rxh6 23. fxe7 Rxh3 24. exd8=Q+ Kxd8 25. Kh1 f5 26. Bb8 Kc8 27. Ba7 Kb7 28. Bxd4 Nxd4 29. c3 Ne6 30. Rxf5 h5 31. Rf7+ Kc8 32. Rg2 c5 33. Rgf2 c4 34. Rf8+ Nxf8 35. Rxf8+ Kc7 36. Rf7+ Kb8 37. dxc4 bxc4 38. Rf4 a4 39. Rxc4 Kb7 40. Rb4+ Kc6 41. Rxa4 Kb7 42. Rb4+ Kc6 43. a4 Kc7 44. a5 Kc6 45. a6 Kc5 46. a7 Rxh2+ 47. Kxh2 h4 48. gxh4 Kd6 49. h5 Kc5 50. h6 Kd6 51. h7 Kc5 52. h8=Q Kd6 53. Qf6+ Kd7 54. Rd4+ Kc7 55. Qd6+ Kb7 56. a8=Q+ Kxa8 57. Rb4 Ka7 58. Qb6+ Ka8 59. Ra4#
```

Against AI of multiplayerchess.com

I had fun with this one, I never knew AI will make blunders :3
Also, if you can analyze my game for me will be appreciated.

Comment: There're many mistakes. Let's focus on materials. 10.f4 is simply bad, 10.g3 then 11.0-0 is a better idea. There're others, too many than I can list here. I'll leave it someone else giving you a full analysis.

Comment: There are some good chess sites that offer game analysis by a computer engine for free. For instance, chess.com or https://chess24.com/en/analysis. The engine will spot your mistakes instantly, so maybe such a tool is interesting for you?

Comment: Not my real game, actually Student T I make more risky plays than this.

Comment: How did you pick the AI level? I played a game in multiplayerchess.com and i was able to beat the computer.

Answer (score 1):

2...d5 risky but playable,

3.Ne2 not that good either Nf3 o exd5

3...g5? positionally bad, better dxe4 and later QxQ taking away castle to white or better develop a piece

4.Nc3 provocative but later N is uncomfortable in b5 and ends badly in a3

6...Bxa3 fine now white has some holes too in the pawn structure

7...b5? again positionally unsound **it appears black does not know how to develop pieces**

8.Rb1 what for? better Ng3 and later Be2 to complete development and control the white squares that are weak for black

10.f4?? till 12.Bxf4 why? this is not correct, simply loses material white is close to lost: as above you had to develop with Ng3, Be2 and 0-0

13...Qe4 a useless check that forgets the B in a2 under attack and returns the material advantage

till 21.e5 relatively normal play (no huge blunders) but 21...Rg6?? loses material in 3 moves sequence (white takes Q R and N vs Q and B) 21...Nd5 was better: after 24...Kxd8 white is totally winning

26.Bb8 till 28.Bxd4 this again was a useless material sacrifice why go in b8 in the firs place? You had to rearrange pieces bringing the rook from a2 to e1 and start attacking: white is still winning but it is harder

30... h5?? is a huge blunder and black is again totally lost now: the rook is trapped and can be captured with Kg2, a move you never played

32.Rg2?? white had to play Kg2 attacking the Rh3 now black could free it with 32...h4, but this remains valid for just a move

from now on white wins by taking all the black pawns which was fine still the rook hanging in h3 was to be taken with Kg2 attacking it-

as suggested you should learn the basics of material counting